# ElasticSearch: Active_Primary_sherds is 0 and active shards also 0

Tags: elasticsearch

I have tried to install Elastic search on AWS with 3 instances with 1 master node and 2 data nodes. I have followed the steps mentioned  https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-elasticsearch-on-aws.

Below is the elasticsearch.yml setting that I have edit based on the need.

```
node.master= true

node.data= true

node.ingest= true

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts = [list of ip of nodes]
```

I have started the elastic service and it is running the status is green. 
Following is the output of `curl -XGET http:// privateip:9200/_cluster/health?pretty`

`{
  "cluster_name" : "EduGrowthElastic",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 3,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}`

I am worried for the active sherds are zero and every other field about the sherds.

I would be very happy if anybody can help me on this. This is my first post sorry for the mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just installed and started Elasticsearch without indexing any data then those numbers are correct.

No data means no index which also means no shards, and hence why all shard numbers are 0.

The only thing that matters at this point is that the status is green!